# Can I put my Firebase contact form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I have this contact form :

```
    <form id="contactForm">

    <div class="alert" style="display:none;">Votre message a bien été envoyé!</div>

    <label for="name">Votre nom</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <label for="email">Votre adresse mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

    <label for="message">Votre message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

and I have initialized firebase in a JS file :

```
config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBjG8pVZ9xg7v_TNDXNbIg7FC51RaMpdJM",
  authDomain: "contactform-2a547.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://contactform-2a547.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "contactform-2a547",
  storageBucket: "contactform-2a547.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "893979452513"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Can I use my contact form in Angular? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Why couldn't you? What happens if you try?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Be careful about copy/pasting sensitive data like you just did (API keys, etc...). You should anonymize it as much as you can before posting it on a public website.

Comment: @YoukouleleY it's not that big of a deal. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/2530536

Answer (score 0):

Using a Firebase database with your Angular website is surprisingly easy.

**1. The first step is knowing how to reference the database so you can use it.**

You have already initialized your Firebase DB so this is good. I would put this code snippet in whatever typescript component you want to communicate with the database.

`firebase.database()` is how we will reference our database.

The Firebase database has a tree structure with a set of nodes where each node can have a child node. Each node can be referenced using the `ref()` method, so

`firebase.database().ref(node)` is how we will reference a node.

For example we can reference (or create if it didn't already exist) a node called "messages" by writing

```
var ref = database.ref("messages");
```

and the variable `ref` will reference it.

**2. Every time we want to put new information to a node we can use the `push()` method.**

For example, if we want to push a string to our `"messages"` node, we can write:

```
ref.push("hello world");
```

This will make a new child node under `"messages"` with the string `"hello world"`.

You can also use this to push an object with multiple variables instead of just a string to get all the information you need in a single node.

Your `database.rules.json` file lists who is able to read or write to your database. You can either change this manually in the file or go to Database > Rules in your Firebase console view.

Read more about database rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

If it is still unclear this video is a robust introduction to Firebase databases: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lEU1UEw3YI